# Coordinator node failed to join the elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to add a coordinator node to my cluster, but I am facing this error when I run it :

```
[2020-09-22T14:03:00,808][INFO ][o.e.c.c.JoinHelper       ] [coordinator-node] failed to join {MASTER-02}{7ZSdp7FQQaa_34eM2LQzjA}{-HOAFDSlSF-iDOnE4ZSdFg}{10.13.81.12}{10.13.81.12:9300}{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=8365060096, ml.max_open_jobs=20, xpack.installed=true, data=hot, transform.node=true} with JoinRequest{sourceNode={coordinator-node}{Wb5iaDUWS5qKmiO7P9ABEg}{KvuU9jjPROCcCFdHyvon1g}{10.13.81.40}{10.13.81.40:9300}{xpack.installed=true, transform.node=false}, minimumTerm=74, optionalJoin=Optional[Join{term=74, lastAcceptedTerm=0, lastAcceptedVersion=0, sourceNode={coordinator-node}{Wb5iaDUWS5qKmiO7P9ABEg}{KvuU9jjPROCcCFdHyvon1g}{10.13.81.40}{10.13.81.40:9300}{xpack.installed=true, transform.node=false}, targetNode={MASTER-02}{7ZSdp7FQQaa_34eM2LQzjA}{-HOAFDSlSF-iDOnE4ZSdFg}{10.13.81.12}{10.13.81.12:9300}{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=8365060096, ml.max_open_jobs=20, xpack.installed=true, data=hot, transform.node=true}}]}
```

And the error in the master node is :

```
[2020-09-22T14:00:14,731][WARN ][o.e.c.c.Coordinator      ] [MASTER-02] failed to validate incoming join request from node [{coordinator-node}{Wb5iaDUWS5qKmiO7P9ABEg}{KvuU9jjPROCcCFdHyvon1g}{10.13.81.40}{10.13.81.40:9300}{xpack.installed=true, transform.node=false}]
org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [coordinator-node][10.13.81.40:9300][internal:cluster/coordination/join/validate]
```

The configuration of the coordinator node is:

```
cluster.name: ClusterName
node.master: false
node.data: false
node.ingest: false
network.host: 10.13.81.40
http.port: 9200
discovery.seed_hosts: ["@IP Master-1", "@IP Master-2", "@IP Master-3"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["name master-1", "name master-2", "name master-3"]
```

Could someone tell me where is the mistake please !
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Can You update the question with full log

Comment: Could possibly be related to this issue: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/failed-to-join-cluster/187511/2 Nuke your ES data folder and try again?

Comment: I deleted the data and tried again but it's the same issue